# haproxy - add current port to header

Tags: linux, proxy, apache, haproxy

I'd like to add current port number to the header.
I tried:

```
reqadd      port:\ dst_port
```

but it adds `dst_port` instead of number.

Is there any way to add variable dst_port do the header?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

http-request set-header X-Port  %[dst_port]

(should work with haproxy 1.5)

Comment: user2414223 you saved my life! I was searching for a little bit different configuration. I tried: http-request set-header X-Port %[src_port] and it seems to work well! Now I can log in Apache the source port with %{X-Port}i Great!